# Canvasjs not drawing chart unless it is refreshed

Tags: javascript, canvasjs

I am building a drill down tool based on driver behaviour gathered by GPS tracking.  The tool will restrict the user to viewing only the organisations allocated to them.  Each layer displays a chart (CanvasJs).  Clicking on a chart section drills down to a new chart. Layers start at 0 (top) and currently end at 3 (bottom)

0. Donut chart.  EventTypes/Counts of ie: EventType: X

   Bar chart.  Drivers with Count of Selected Event Type  ie: Name, X Events.

   Scatter Chart.  All of Drivers EventType Events in Period.  ie: Each dot represents an event on time line

   Line Chart.  Speed of Vehicle vs Time.  We include a time offset before and after the event to show context.  Currently 2 minutes bracket.

Layer 3 is currently causing issues.

- Ajax requests data from a .net core 2.0 mvc page.
- The Callback is triggered. The data comes back (I can see it in the inspection tools.)
- It is assigned to the data section of chartOption[i] object
- The chartOption[i] is assigned to a chart via its constructor.
- That chart is then told to render.
- The chart has a correct Y axis, with units.  The X axis has the correct label, but no units.  The center is blank.

### [image: Chart displaying nothing]

- Changing the date forces a refresh.

  ```
  $('#processDate').change(function(e) {
      param.datePassedIn = e.target.value;
      doAjax(layer.current);
  });
  ```
- Layer 3 does not actually use the date.  It requires the eventId only.  This is why the event stays the same.
- The chart body displays correctly.
- The X axis changes to display values, but is displaying the label values, not the X value.

[image: Chart displaying but has wrong X axis]

---

**layer 3 chart options**

All chart options are in an array object, with the index being the layer id.

```
var chartOptions = [
    {
        [snip]
    },
    {
        [snip]
    },
    {
        [snip]
    },
    { //layer 3
        cursor: "pointer",
        title: {
            text: orgCode + " Events",
            fontSize: 30
        },
        subtitles: [{
            text: "{EventType} Events {EventId} for Driver {DriverId}", // this comes from the MVC now
            fontSize: 15
        }],
        axisY: {
            title: "Speed",
            stripLines: {},
            minimum: 0,
            maximum: 130                
        },
        axisX: {
            title: "Time",
            labelAngle: 90,
            labelAutoFit: false,
            interval: 1,
            intervalType: "minute",
            valueFormatString: "HH:mm:ss",
            minimum: periodStart,
            maximum: periodEnd

        },
        data: [
            {
                type: "line",
                //click: layer3ClickHandler,  //we're not clicking down. at the bottom.
                dataPoints: []
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

**ajaxOptionas and doAjax function**

```
var ajaxOptions  = [
    {

        url: "DriverBehaviour/GetLayer0",
        callback : layer0CallbackHandler
    },
    {
        url: "DriverBehaviour/GetLayer1",
        callback : layer1CallbackHandler

    },
    {
        url: "DriverBehaviour/GetLayer2",
        callback : layer2CallbackHandler

    },
    {
        url: "DriverBehaviour/GetLayer3",
        callback : layer3CallbackHandler

    }
];


//AJAX call based on current layer.  Returns to designated callback handler (in options)
function doAjax(layerIndex) {
    logObjectAsJson(ajaxOptions[layerIndex], "ajaxOptions[" + layerIndex + "]");
    logObjectAsJson(param, "param");
    hideErrorText();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        url: ajaxOptions[layerIndex].url,
        data: param, 
        success: function (response) {
            showErrorText(response);
            ajaxOptions[layerIndex].callback(response);
        },
        complete : function () {
            console.log("Ajax call complete");
        }
    });
}
```

**layer 3 callback handler**

It's job is to prepare any data for the chart, and any other rendering options.  It also emits an HTML list and table.

```
function layer3CallbackHandler(data) {
    console.log("func start layer3CallbackHandler");
    console.log("Current Layer: " + layer.current);

    /******** Prepare chart **********/
    chartOptions[layer.current].axisX.minimum = formatDateInputLong(new Date(data.periodStart));
    console.log("min date: " + chartOptions[layer.current].axisX.minimum);

    chartOptions[layer.current].axisX.maximum = formatDateInputLong(new Date(data.periodEnd));
    console.log("max date: " + chartOptions[layer.current].axisX.maximum);

    chartOptions[layer.current].data[0].dataPoints = [];
    $.each(data.dataPoints, function (key, value) {
        chartOptions[layer.current].data[0].dataPoints.push({
            label: value["label"],
            x: new Date(value["Xdate"]),
            y: value["y"],
            color: value["color"],
            name: value["name"]
        });
    });

    chartOptions[layer.current].subtitles[0].text = data.chartSubTitle;
    chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", chartOptions[layer.current]); 
    logObjectAsJson(chart, "chart");
    chart.render();


    $("#processDate").disabled = true; //disable the date picker - date not used on layer 3
    $("#backButton").show();

    $("#tableContainer").empty();
    $("#tableContainer").append("<h2>Event Details</h2>");

    layer3emitList(data.tableData[0]);

    layer3emitTable(data.tableData);

    console.log("func end layer3CallbackHandler");
}
```

**Chart object**

This is the chart object logged just before rendering.  Its a combination of the `chartOptions[3]` and the data returned from the Ajax query and combined in the `layer3CallbackHandler`

```
chart
{
    "options": {
        "cursor": "pointer",
        "title": {
            "text": "HVO Events",
            "fontSize": 30
        },
        "subtitles": [
            {
                "text": "Driving w/o Seatbelt Event 4484051 for Driver Wayne Hicks",
                "fontSize": 15
            }
        ],
        "axisY": {
            "title": "Speed",
            "stripLines": {},
            "minimum": 0,
            "maximum": 130
        },
        "axisX": {
            "title": "Time",
            "labelAngle": 90,
            "labelAutoFit": false,
            "interval": 1,
            "intervalType": "minute",
            "valueFormatString": "HH:mm:ss",
            "minimum": "2019-12-01 06:50:41",
            "maximum": "2019-12-01 06:53:05"
        },
        "data": [
            {
                "type": "line",
                "dataPoints": [
                    {
                        "label": "Start up",
                        "x": "2019-11-30T19:50:41.000Z",
                        "y": 0,
                        "color": "black",
                        "name": "06:50:41"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Seatbelt; (GPS Unlock)",
                        "x": "2019-11-30T19:50:43.000Z",
                        "y": 0,
                        "color": "black",
                        "name": "06:50:43"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Seatbelt; (GPS Unlock)",
                        "x": "2019-11-30T19:50:45.000Z",
                        "y": 0,
                        "color": "black",
                        "name": "06:50:45"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Seatbelt",
                        "x": "2019-11-30T19:50:50.000Z",
                        "y": 0,
                        "color": "black",
                        "name": "06:50:50"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Seatbelt",
                        "x": "2019-11-30T19:50:55.000Z",
                        "y": 15,
                        "color": "red",
                        "name": "06:50:55"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Seatbelt",
                        "x": "2019-11-30T19:51:00.000Z",
                        "y": 19,
                        "color": "red",
                        "name": "06:51:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Seatbelt",
                        "x": "2019-11-30T19:51:05.000Z",
                        "y": 14,
                        "color": "red",
                        "name": "06:51:05"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Driving",
                        "x": "2019-11-30T19:51:10.000Z",
                        "y": 28,
                        "color": "black",
                        "name": "06:51:10"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Driving",
                        "x": "2019-11-30T19:51:15.000Z",
                        "y": 22,
                        "color": "black",
                        "name": "06:51:15"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Driver Tag Presented",
                        "x": "2019-11-30T19:51:15.000Z",
                        "y": 22,
                        "color": "black",
                        "name": "06:51:15"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Driving",
                        "x": "2019-11-30T19:51:20.000Z",
                        "y": 40,
                        "color": "black",
                        "name": "06:51:20"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Driving",
                        "x": "2019-11-30T19:51:25.000Z",
                        "y": 46,
                        "color": "black",
                        "name": "06:51:25"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Driving",
                        "x": "2019-11-30T19:51:30.000Z",
                        "y": 35,
                        "color": "black",
                        "name": "06:51:30"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Driving",
                        "x": "2019-11-30T19:51:35.000Z",
                        "y": 49,
                        "color": "black",
                        "name": "06:51:35"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Driving",
                        "x": "2019-11-30T19:51:40.000Z",
                        "y": 39,
                        "color": "black",
                        "name": "06:51:40"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Driving",
                        "x": "2019-11-30T19:51:44.000Z",
                        "y": 28,
                        "color": "black",
                        "name": "06:51:44"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Driving",
                        "x": "2019-11-30T19:51:45.000Z",
                        "y": 28,
                        "color": "black",
                        "name": "06:51:45"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Driving",
                        "x": "2019-11-30T19:51:50.000Z",
                        "y": 23,
                        "color": "black",
                        "name": "06:51:50"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Driving",
                        "x": "2019-11-30T19:51:55.000Z",
                        "y": 42,
                        "color": "black",
                        "name": "06:51:55"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Driving",
                        "x": "2019-11-30T19:52:00.000Z",
                        "y": 55,
                        "color": "black",
                        "name": "06:52:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Driving",
                        "x": "2019-11-30T19:52:05.000Z",
                        "y": 55,
                        "color": "black",
                        "name": "06:52:05"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Driving",
                        "x": "2019-11-30T19:52:10.000Z",
                        "y": 49,
                        "color": "black",
                        "name": "06:52:10"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Driving",
                        "x": "2019-11-30T19:52:15.000Z",
                        "y": 53,
                        "color": "black",
                        "name": "06:52:15"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Driving",
                        "x": "2019-11-30T19:52:20.000Z",
                        "y": 53,
                        "color": "black",
                        "name": "06:52:20"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Driving",
                        "x": "2019-11-30T19:52:24.000Z",
                        "y": 34,
                        "color": "black",
                        "name": "06:52:24"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Driving",
                        "x": "2019-11-30T19:52:25.000Z",
                        "y": 29,
                        "color": "black",
                        "name": "06:52:25"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Driving",
                        "x": "2019-11-30T19:52:30.000Z",
                        "y": 35,
                        "color": "black",
                        "name": "06:52:30"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Driving",
                        "x": "2019-11-30T19:52:35.000Z",
                        "y": 39,
                        "color": "black",
                        "name": "06:52:35"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Driving",
                        "x": "2019-11-30T19:52:40.000Z",
                        "y": 38,
                        "color": "black",
                        "name": "06:52:40"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Driving",
                        "x": "2019-11-30T19:52:44.000Z",
                        "y": 31,
                        "color": "black",
                        "name": "06:52:44"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Driving",
                        "x": "2019-11-30T19:52:45.000Z",
                        "y": 31,
                        "color": "black",
                        "name": "06:52:45"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Driving",
                        "x": "2019-11-30T19:52:50.000Z",
                        "y": 27,
                        "color": "black",
                        "name": "06:52:50"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Driving",
                        "x": "2019-11-30T19:52:55.000Z",
                        "y": 23,
                        "color": "black",
                        "name": "06:52:55"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Driving",
                        "x": "2019-11-30T19:53:00.000Z",
                        "y": 20,
                        "color": "black",
                        "name": "06:53:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Driving",
                        "x": "2019-11-30T19:53:05.000Z",
                        "y": 23,
                        "color": "black",
                        "name": "06:53:05"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Small Console Logging Function**

Uses `JSON.stringify` to pretty print to the console

```
function logObjectAsJson(object, name) {
    var str;
    if (name == undefined) {
        str = JSON.stringify(object, null, 4);
    }
    else {
        str = name + "\n" + JSON.stringify(object, null, 4);
    }

    console.log(str);
}
```

Finally I have the most recent build deployed to [this site](https://www.ctrackonline.com.au/DashboardTest)

1. Why doesn't the chart display correctly?
2. What is causing the X index to shift to the label when it is reloaded?

Comment: Try changing `"x": "2019-11-30T19:53:05.000Z",` to `"x": new Date("2019-11-30T19:53:05.000Z"),`

Comment: Sorry, was on annual leave.  The x value in the chart object is a results of `x: new Date(value["Xdate"])` The asp collection returns `x` or `xdate` depending on type.